# jQuery Slider - Dynamic Height on Mobile & Refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a issue with a slider. I want the slider height to change to the height of the image present. This works on desktop, but seems to break on mobile.

Additionally, when the page is refreshed manually, the initial height isn't set. I read this was due to the `ready()` function, and to use a `onload` with a interval init, which I tried to do, but the whole slider breaks with `onload` and the interval in use.

http://www.nwdastore.com/slideshow-test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove `min-height: 450px` from `#slider-container` since the slider has a height less than 450px when the device is mobile.

```
#slider-container {
    background: rgb(1,1,1);
    margin: 0 auto -10px auto;
    max-width: 1440px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Makes me feel a little dumb. lol I removed the actual height element, of course **min**-height is the cause.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the second part of the dynamic height? When page is manually refreshed the height cannot be accurately grabbed.

Comment: I think it happens because you forget to dynamically set height inside `prevSlide()` the same way you did on `nextSlide()`. I'm not sure, but I think that's it. Of course, there are probably more details to improve.

Comment: When you F5 to refresh, the first slide is not present at all because the `min-height` is missing. This means that the script that gets the height of the hidden/visibl  elements suddenly cannot get the height when you manually refresh with F5 versus clicking "Go" with the address bar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314058/jquery-height-returns-different-results-using-f5-or-ctrlf5 This seems to be the problem, and solution, but it breaks my slider when using `load`. The slider never initiates, even with the interval being started when load is finished.

Comment: I resolved the refresh issue. I was trying to use `onload` with the `document` rather than the `window`. Woops. After that self initiation was no issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you did it. I was going to try to help you later, but now it's done. Yes, onload is appropriate that way. See, I also missed that silly detail. :)